# Can you extract Facebook data by date range using Facepager?

Tags: facebook

I've been using Facepager for research purposes for almost a year now and I can't figure out how to extract data - public posts, comments and likes from a page, for instance - by date range. While other programs such as Netvizz gives me this option, Facepager seems to fail to do so.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. It is not clear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `since` and `until` parameters for this, e.g. set `since` (left side in parameter settings) to `2017-09-13` (right side) when fetching posts of a page. See the section Time Based Navigation in the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api?locale=en_US#time).

Keep in mind that accessing very old data with the API is limited by Faceebok. Most social media platforms are aligned to the presence :)

BTW: we just opened a [Group on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/136224396995428/) for getting help.

Comment: Thank you very much, @strohne! I'll check that Facebook group out.